# Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-2 and the size of the right side is 2-by-2

Tags: matlab

[image]

the code tries to implement the Euler's method and improve Euler's method to second order differential equations but there is a dimensionality error with the ys values array which store the values of y and dy

```
f=@(x,y) [y(2); (2/x)*y(2)-(2/x^2)*y(1)];     % function through a function handle
x0 = 1; y0 = [4,9]; xf=2;                          % IC

    % Improve and Euler's Method
    [xs,ys] = ode45(f,[x0,xf],y0);
    [xsi1,ysi1] = Ieuler(f,[x0,xf],y0,0.1);
    [xse1,yse1] = euler(f,[x0,xf],y0,0.1);
    [xsi2,ysi2] = Ieuler(f,[x0,xf],y0,0.5);
    [xse2,yse2] = euler(f,[x0,xf],y0,0.5);
    
    % plotting all solutions
    plot(xsi1,ysi1(:,1),'-b','LineWidth',1.5); hold on;
    plot(xse1,yse1(:,1),'-r','LineWidth',1.5); hold on;
    plot(xsi2,ysi2(:,1),'-g','LineWidth',1.5); hold on;
    plot(xse2,yse2(:,1),'-k','LineWidth',1.5); hold on;
    plot(xs,ys(:,1),'-b','LineWidth',1.5); hold on;
    axis([0 xf -0.1 4]); xlabel('x');ylabel('y')
```

In the second part of the code are the constructed function to implement Euler's method

```
%Function calls
% function: Euler's Method implementation
function [xs,ys] = euler(f,xv,y0,h)
  x0 = xv(1); X = xv(2);
  N = (X-x0)/h;
  xs = zeros(N+1,1); ys = zeros(N+1,length(y0));
  x = x0; y = y0;
  xs(1) = x; ys(1,:) = y';
  for i = 1:N
      s1 = f(x,y);                  %evaluate direction field at current point
      y= y+s1*h;                    %find new y
      x = x+h;
      xs(i+1) = x; ys(i+1,:) = y';  %store y(1), y(2) in a row array
  end
end
% function: Improved Euler's Method implementation
function [xs,ys] = Ieuler(f,xv,y0,h)
  x0 = xv(1); X = xv(2);
  N = (X-x0)/h;
  xs = zeros(N+1,1); ys = zeros(N+1,length(y0));
  x = x0; y = y0;
  xs(1) = x; ys(1,:) = y';
  for i = 1:N
      s1 = f(x,y);                  %evaluate direction field at current point
      yE= y+s1*h;                   %find Euler value yE
      s2 = f(x+h,yE);               %evalute direction field at Euler point
      y = y + h*((s1+s2)/2);        *%find new y*
      x = x+h;
      xs(i+1) = x; ys(i+1,:) = y';  *%store y(1), y(2) in a row array* 
  end
end
```

```
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-2 and the
size of the right side is 2-by-2.

Error in Untitled>Ieuler (line 63)
      xs(i) = x; ys(i,:) = y';

Error in Untitled (line 20) 
    [xsi1,ysi1] = Ieuler(f,[x0,xf],y0,0.1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. stop writing several logic lines (terminated with a `;`) in one text
   line. It is not even clear, which command causes the error, since
   there are two in this line! (BTW, it is this `ys(i+1,:) = y';`)
2. strip your code. You should provide a *minimal reproducible example*
   (its not an art contest... and as the error occurs in `Ieuler` the rest is not necessary).
3. **your error is**: that your function handle ´f´ returns a vector, but `y` is an array => you'll get a matrix, which you want to assign to an array `ys(i+1,:) = y'` (for whatever reason you are transposing this). **solution:** let `f` return an array: `f=@(x,y) [y(2), (2/x)*y(2)-(2/x^2)*y(1)];` (note the comma) or transpose its return value `s1 = f(x,y).';` (its good practice to use the `.'` for non-complex transpositions -- for clarity.

**Advice:** have a look how to debug in MATLAB. You probably could have tracked this down by placing a breakpoint just before the line where the error occurs (or even activate *Pause on Errors*) and checking the dimensions.